# computing $\lim_{X \to \infty }((x^3+2x)^\frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{x^2-2x})$

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{X \to \infty }((x^3+2x)^\frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{x^2-2x})$

Anyone have a nice elegent way wo solve it? i tried L'Hôpital's rule but didn't work.
also i tried to multiple by Conjugation and it failed too.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+2x}-x= x\Bigl(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac 2{x^2}}-1\Bigr)\sim \frac 2{3x}\to 0$$
$$\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x= x\Bigl(\sqrt{1-\frac 2x}-1\Bigr)\to -1$$
Consequently:
$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+2x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x}=(\sqrt[3]{x^3+2x}-x)-(\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x)\to 1$$.

Comment: why $\sqrt[3]{x^3+2x}-x= x\Bigl(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac 2{x^2}}-1\Bigr)\sim \frac 2{3x}\to 0$?

Comment: didnt get how you know that it's $\frac{2}{3x}$

Comment: By conjugation: $\sqrt[3]{1+\frac 2{x^2}}-1=\frac{\frac 2{x^2}}{\Bigl(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac 2{x^2}}\Bigr)^2+\Bigl(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac 2{x^2}}\Bigr)+1}$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's elegant in your eyes but it's at least efficace

$$(x^3+2x)^\frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{x^2-2x}=x\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)^{1/3}-x\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{1/2}\sim_\infty 1$$ 
using that
$$(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$$

Comment: didn't understand how you got from the last part to $1$ also i dont get why: $(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$

Comment: We have by Taylor series
$$f(x)\sim_0 f(0)+xf'(0)$$
so applying this gives $(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$

Comment: ok but you did $\sim_0$ and in the question it's for infinity that's what i don't get i guess.

Comment: The term $\frac 2{x^2}$ tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: that i know but something doesn't seem right to me. there's a difference between saying the result approaches $0$ than saying $x$ is approaches $0$. and you say that you have used $(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$ but that's true when $x$ approaching $0$. in your answer $(1+\frac{2}{x^2})$ at $x$ approach to $0$ it tends to infinity and when $x$ approach infinity so you got $0$ but then you have $x(1)-x(1)$ and it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It **can** be done by conjugation, but it is not pleasant to type.  We sketch the approach. We are looking at
$$((x^3+2x)^2)^{1/6} -((x^2-2x)^3)^{1/6}=u-v.$$
Multiply top and missing bottom by $u^5+u^4v+u^3v^2+u^2v^3+uv^4+v^5$.

On top we get $u^6-v^6$, a polynomial with lead term $6x^5$. At the bottom, we get $6$ terms each of which asymptotically behaves like $x^5$. Dividing top and bottom by $x^5$ and manipulating a bit gives us limit $1$.

**Remark:** Looking at the beginning of the Taylor expansions is the "right" way to do the problem.

Comment: thanks but it looks hard for me and can't get it down by your approach

Comment: It is hard to type. Turn the thing upside down (reciprocal). first term is $\frac{(x^3+2x)^2)^{5/6}}{6x^5}$. Divide top and bottom by $x^5$. It is messy, Taylor series are far better, as I indicated in the answer. But it *can* be done by "conjugates." Better, take the sixth power, and look at the leading powers of $x$.

Comment: ok ill try it too

Comment: Not worth it unless you are in a masochistic mood. Because of experience, I see the "rough size." But if one has to calculate, and what's worse LaTeX the calculation, it gets a whole lot not fun.